# DB creation in rails using the rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rakefile

I am trying to create a testing DB.
I used the following command :

```
  rake db:schema:create
```

also tried various versions of code such as

```
sudo bundle exec rake db:create
```

I keep getting the same error :

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: no such file to load -- bundler/setup
/home/eshel/test/test_db/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top>'
/home/eshel/test/test_db/config/application.rb:1:in `<top>'
/home/eshel/test/test_db/config/application.rb:1:in `<top>'
/home/eshel/test/test_db/Rakefile:1:in `(root)'
/home/eshel/test/test_db/Rakefile:5:in `(root)'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Tried to install bundles many times but nothing worked so far.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Have you installed bundler?

Comment: bundle install is working properly?

Comment: Run `gem install bundler` and retry. _Sidenote_: please do not use `sudo` until you do understand what `sudo` is for.

Comment: yes I used this command : sudo bundle install

Comment: @Eshel: Please specify rails version which you are working now.

Comment: Rails 4.1.10
Ruby jruby 9.0.3.0
Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: @Chakreshwar Sharma any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
rake db:create
```

Comment: It gave me this line :

      Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 51 gems now installed.
    Bundled gems are installed into /home/eshel/main_server.

does it matter if i want them in a different place ? other than main_server folder ?

Comment: Could this be a problem with the jruby and ruby versions I am running ? I can't set the jruby and ruby versions to the ones that appear in the rvm list

Comment: try using `bundle exec rake db:create`.

Comment: Try to Install ruby with rvm with its latest version & then reinstall rails & execute above commands

Comment: Thanks !
I had a mismatch between the ruby and jruby versions that my app was using, after I worked it out, the above commands did the trick :) Thanks for your help